# Junit 5 suite is not running tests in command line

Tags: junit5

I am trying to run `TestSuite` using `Junit 5`. Individual file run fine. But `TestSuite` is not running when executed from command line. I am using `junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.0.jar` to run tests.

My Test classes are:

```
package demo;
    
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    
public class TestDemoClass1 {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test 1 from DemoClass 1");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test2 from DemoClass 1");
    }
}
```

My Suite calss is:

```
package demo;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
    
@Suite
@SelectClasses({ TestDemoClass1.class })
public class TestSuite {

}
```

The command I am usign to run from command lines:

```
java -jar target/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.0.jar -cp .;target/test-classes/ -c demo.TestSuite
```

Comment: Output of this command is:    
        Thanks for using JUnit! Support its development at https://junit.org sponsoring    
         Test run finished after 67 ms
    [         2 containers found      ]
    [         0 containers skipped    ]
    [         2 containers started    ]
    [         0 containers aborted    ]
    [         2 containers successful ]
    [         0 containers failed     ]
    [         0 tests found           ]

Comment: Suite has not been around before version 1.8. So there’s definitely a mismatch between the standalone jar 1.6.0 and the version you use for compilation.

Comment: I tried with same version of jar but still same result. Dont know whats wrong as no error or exception I used :java -jar target/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar -cp .;target/test-classes/ -c demo.TestSuite

Comment: One more thing: you have to add the jar of the suite engine to the classpath. It’s not Jupiter that runs a suite but the suite engine.

Comment: Done that @johanneslink . Added to POM and compiles . Still same result no luck

Comment: The pom does not determine your classpath when calling java. It’s an additional -cp parameter segment that you need.

Comment: BTW, why using the standalone runner and not just „mvn test“?

Comment: Once this run I will be addign it to a lamda code which will trigger tests after build using AWS lambda. Also I mean I added to POM and ran a build . The jar is available in lib folder now which is also mentione din classpath in my commnad while compiling javac -d target -cp .;target/lib/*;target/multitest-1.0.1.jar;target/multitest-1.0.1-tests.jar;target:junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar src/test/java/demo/*.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved ":https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2813.
The issue was not adding set of jars while runnign command needed for console launcher.
Additional info in above GitHub issue link but in summary you need to add following jars to classpath:
junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar; 
junit-platform-suite-api-1.8.2.jar; 
junit-platform-suite-commons-1.8.2.jar; 
junit-platform-suite-engine-1.8.2.jar; \